# sed command UNIX Groovy

Tags: shell, unix, groovy

I am executing a schellscript update.sh from groovy.the shellscript should update another XML file using sed command,but the XML update is not happening when I run using groovy ,but it is happening when I run the shellscript from command line

groovy

```
def proc = ['/move/update.sh',name].execute()
```

shellscript

```
NAME=$1
sed -i "s/ITEM_NAME/$1/g" script.xml
```

script.xml
is not getting updated when I run using groovy

Comment: Is the groovy process in the right directory?

Comment: I am running groovy with an external program...the groovy is invoing the shellscript also but the shellscript can not update another file when it executed using groovy

Comment: I suggest you put the full path to the xml file into the script: `sed -i ... /path/to/script.xml`

Comment: Also, does the user running the groovy process have (a) rights to execute the script, and (b) rights to modify the xml file?

Comment: it is having the right to execute script , how to check whether it is having the right to modify the XML file? I already updated the XML file property as 7777

Comment: Have you checked `proc.getErr()` for anything on stderr?

Comment: proc.getErr() is sgiving' java.lang.UNIXProcess$ProcessPipeInputStream@525c717d'

Comment: That's a stream: you have to read from it.

Comment: sorry, I did not understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to figure out what is happening with that spawned process instead of asking us. Have a look at this example:

```sh
$ groovysh
Groovy Shell (3.0.4, JVM: 14.0.1)
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
groovy:000> proc = ['sh', '-c', 'echo "this is stdout"; echo "this is stderr">&2; exit 3'].execute()
===> Process[pid=29552, exitValue="not exited"]
groovy:000> proc.err
===> java.lang.ProcessImpl$ProcessPipeInputStream@e154848
groovy:000> proc.err.getText()
===> this is stderr

groovy:000> proc.getText()
===> this is stdout

groovy:000> proc.exitValue()
===> 3
```

That shell script is unnecessary: groovy can invoke directly: Given this

```sh
$ cat script.xml
<item name="ITEM_NAME"/>
$ cat sed.groovy
def name = 'this is the item name'
def cmd = ['sed', '-i', '', "s/ITEM_NAME/${name}/", 'script.xml']
println cmd
def proc = cmd.execute()
println proc.exitValue()
println proc.err.getText()
println proc.getText()
```

Note that I'm on a Mac where sed's `-i` option requires a value. Adjust that code if you use GNU sed.

Running it looks like this

```sh
$ groovy sed.groovy
[sed, -i, , s/ITEM_NAME/this is the item name/, script.xml]
0


$ cat script.xml
<item name="this is the item name"/>
```

On the other hand, groovy can read a file, make text replacements, and write a file, so you don't need to call out to sed at all.